# Find the Cardinality of points on a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

$n$ points are distributed on the perimeter of a circle. We connect each $2$ points with a straight line, and we get the set $S$ of the chords.

(1) Find $|S|$
(2) Assuming that there are no inner point in the circle that lies on more than $2$ chords in $S$, how many intersection points there are between the chords in $S$ ?

My answer:

I don't know how to make it formal but I've found that the formula is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ The only thing I can say that sounds formal is that we connect each point ($n$) with the other $n-1$ points so it's $n(n-1)$, but if we connect point $P_1$ with $P_2$ then we don't need to connect $P_2$ with $P_1$ again so we 'remove' duplicates by dividing by $2$

For (2) I have no idea where to start, I would appreciate your help on explaining how make (1) formal and how to get started with (2)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ is correct. Can you see that is also the way of choosing two distinct points from $n$, also written ${n \choose 2}$?

Comment: @Henry ohh, you are completely right! $nC2$ does give $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ !

Comment: For (2), you could consider what you need for chords to intersect.  One possibility is they intersect in the interior in which case you need four distinct points *and* you need the chords to cross - Can you count these?  Another may be they intersect on the boundary at one of the $n$ points; there are obvious $n$ places where this happens, but are you supposed to count them?

Comment: @Henry With 4 points I get only 1 intersection, 5 points and I get 5 intersections and with 6 points I get 11 so I don't see the pattern here unfortunately.. :(

Comment: Four points having one intersection is useful:  so how many ways are there of choosing $4$ points from $n$?

Comment: @Henry $nC4 = \frac{n!}{4!(n-4)!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}$ but where is the $1$ here? I am confused :[

Comment: If you have four points selected, you can pair them three different ways to make two chords, but in only one of those three cases do the chords cross inside the circle.  So the answer to (2) is either $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}\times 1$ or $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}\times 1+n$ depending on whether you also count the original $n$ points as intersection points of chords

Comment: @Henry but that is, $nC4$ what is $n$ in this case? I mean, why is the answer $nC4$ specifically why is the 4 specifies the intersections? so $5C4=5$ just like I said but $6C4 = 15$ and not $11$ as I counted (discarding the intersection of the points themselves of the chords)

Comment: It should have been $15$ for $n=6$.  You may have tried a regular hexagon which would give you $13=6+6+1$ but failed the point in your question "*Assuming that there are no inner point in the circle that lies on more than 2 chords in S*".  I do not see how you got $11$

Comment: @Henry but why does $4$ appear in every answer? why is it $6C4$ or $5C4$ ? why is the answer $nC4$ ? Thank you sir!

Comment: Because two chords which do not intersect on the edge of the circle involve four of the original points